# Hyperledger Composer - ACL Rule with function in condition

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to write a little complexer logic in the condition of an ACL Rule as always the `p.getIdentifier() == r.getIdentifier()`, because in my fault it isn't possible.

These are my models:

```
participant Customer identified by customerID {
  o String  customerID
  o String  name
  ...
}

asset A identified by aID {
  o String       aID
  --> Customer   customer
}

asset B identified by bID {
  o String  bID
  --> A     a
}
```

Now I want to give the `Customer` access to see all `B` assets, but only where the relationship to `A` references to an asset, which have a relatinship to the actual participant of `Customer`, who is "logged in".

Summarized logic: From asset `B` to `A`, and then from `A` to `Customer`.

So in this case I can't compare the identifiers of `Customer` and `B` directly and have to go over `A`. Therefore I wanted to evaulate the access with a function which is called in the `script.js` file:

```
rule CustomerAccessCustomer {
  description: "The customer should see all B assets, but only when he have a relationship in asset A "
  participant(p): "org.xxx.test.participant.Customer"
  operation: READ
  resource(r): "org.xxx.test.asset.B"
  condition: (evaluateAccess(p,r))
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Here is the function of the `script.js`:

```
async function evaluateAccess(p,r) {
  try {
    const bRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.xxx.test.asset.B');
    const b = await bRegistry.get(r.getIdentifier());

    const aRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.xxx.test.asset.A');
    const a = await aRegistry.get(b.a.getIdentifier());

    if (p.getIdentifier() === a.customer.getIdentifier()) {
        return true;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

But I get an error `Error: The runtime API is not available`.

Do I think the wrong way, isn't it possible to evaluate access with a function?
How did you handle access rule if you can't just compare the identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just be able to do:

```
rule CustomerAccessCustomer {
  description: "The customer should see all B assets, but only when he have a relationship in asset A "
  participant(p): "org.xxx.test.participant.Customer"
  operation: READ
  resource(r): "org.xxx.test.asset.B"
  condition: ( (p.getIdentifier() === r.a.customer.getIdentifier()) 
  action: ALLOW
}
```

but `p` would also need READ access already to be able to 'read' Asset resource 'A' (to check the identifier etc) in the first place :-)

Comment: I've tried for days, never thougt it could be that simple.. Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The customer should be participant not asset:

```
participant Customer identified by customerID {
  o String  customerID
  o String  name
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I just gave an example and forget to change it here, but in my Business Network the customer is a participant.