# Composer-Playground: "Error: The runtime API is not available"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to use `getType()` API in `permissions.acl` conditions field. When I try to submit transaction using the newly created participant(+identity), i get this error:

> "Error: The runtime API is not available"

`getType()` API is working perfectly fine with `ibm-bluemix composer-playground`.

Why can't I use that in local setup.

Comment: I've used the following rule from trade-network sample eg ```rule DenyUpdatetoTrader {
    description: "Sample check"
    participant(p): "org.example.trading.Trader"
    operation: UPDATE
    resource(r): "org.example.trading.Commodity"
    condition: (r.getType() === "Commodity" )
    action: DENY
}}``` ..and works/evaluates fine (Playground -> local Fabric). I suspect there's an error in your function similar to shown here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423437/hyperledger-composer-acl-rule-with-function-in-condition

Comment: Thanks. I will check and come back.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. In script file, I had declared factory globally ` const factory = getFactory() `. This somehow prevented the ACL with conditions from working properly. When I removed that global factory declaration, it worked fine. 
Why did it make problem? I guess it's because of the way composer acl conditions part designed to work. How does it work actually?